# Insert database into new database with extra column

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in postgresql. I have a table that contains 4 fields. I added a 5th and I guess I broke my database. If I make a backup of my database and then recreate my database with the extra field that I need, will I be able to import the database back in?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - assuming a plain-text backup before you "broke" your database.

It will contain (among other things):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);

...

INSERT INTO tbl(col1,col2,col3,col4)
VALUES
(1,2,3,4),
...
```

Just edit the `CREATE TABLE` line to say:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int);
```

The `INSERT` still works, `col5` will be `NULL` in the new database.

Comment: Is it possible to find my backup? I am not sure the name I used.

Comment: @Halloween: If you didn't make one, you don't have one. It's not done automatically in a standard distribution.